# Expectation of a product of random variables problem

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Let $U$ be a random variable with uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ and a bivariate random vector $(Z,T)$ defined by
$$(Z,T)=(0,0)1_{\{U\geq 2\alpha\}}+(Q_X(U),Q_Y(U))1_{\{U< 2\alpha\}}$$

where $Q_X(u)=inf\{t:P(\mid X \mid>t)\leq u\}$ is the quantile function of $\mid X\mid$, $1_{\{ \cdot\}}$ is the indicator function, $X,Y$ two integrable real-valued random variables and $\alpha$ a real number.
Can someone argue why the following equality is valid?

$$E(ZT)=\int_0^{2\alpha}Q_X(u)Q_Y(u)du.$$

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

Is it correct to write $ZT=Q_X(u)Q_Y(u)1_{\{U< 2\alpha\}}$ from the above definition and then apply expectation:

$$E(ZT)=\int_0^{2\alpha}Q_x(U)Q_Y(U)dP  ?$$

Comment: Could you please explain why "$(0,0)1_{\{U\geq 2\alpha\}}$" appears at all?  When will it ever be nonzero?

Comment: It seems to follow directly from $$Z\times T=0\times 0 \times\Bbb 1_{U\ge2\alpha}+Q_X(U)\times Q_Y(U)\times \Bbb 1_{U<2\alpha}$$